# Open set equivalence

Tags: general-topology

I am beginning topology and need to show a very basic statement but I feel like the statement is more like a definition and there is nothing to prove :

I have the following definition : A set $E \in \mathbb R^n$ is open if $\forall x \in E, \exists \delta_x > 0 \text{ such that } B(x,\delta_x) \subset E$.

I need to show : E is open $\iff$ $E=\mathring{E}$ ($E$ is equal to its interior).

$\Rightarrow$ : Supposing that $E$ is open, if we take an arbitrary $x \in E$, then $\exists \delta_x > 0 \text{ such that } B(x,\delta_x) \subset E$. It follows that $E=\mathring{E}$.

$\Leftarrow$ : Pretty much same argument.

Is there something else to prove that I am missing ? Maybe need to show in the first implication that $\partial E$ is not included in E (as we usually have $E = \mathring{E} \cup \partial E$).

Comment: What is your working definition of interior? Right now your proof is just a restatement of the provided definition of an open set in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Definition of interior: Define $\mathring{E}$ to be the set of all $x$ for which there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon(x)\subset E$. If that's your definition, your proof is completely correct and yes, it's that simple.

Comment: Yes it is @amsmath, ok then I guess this is just a very basic thing to prove.

Comment: Another common definition of the interior of $E$ is the largest open subset of $E$, equivalently the union of all open subsets of $E$. If that is your definition of interior then that gives you something less tautological to prove.

Comment: As @paulblartmathcop mentioned the interior of $E$ is just defined as $$\bigcup_{U_i \in \mathcal{P}(E) \text{open}} U_i.$$ This should be enough to work with. Note that the $B(x,\delta_x)$ you have looks like these $U_i$, it is an element of power set and is open in $E$.